# How can I disable anchor pointer events while keeping them for anchor children?

Tags: html, css, pointer-events

I have an anchor element that has several children inside. Requirements changed and now anchor  might or might not have a link on it. The easiest way to change it would be to disable click events for anchor  and keep it for children (they have some functionality that depends on pointer events).

When I apply `pointer-events: none` to the anchor  parent, everything is fine - the link doesn't work. When I then apply `pointer-events: auto` to anchor  children, the link becomes active again.

The generated html is like so:

```
<a href class='no-pointer-events'>
    <figure class='pointer-events-auto'></figure>
</a>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Well, [it works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/zhykduxs/)

Comment: Parent link still lights up when Figure is clicked in the fiddle.

Comment: You’ll have to stop propagation with a bit of JS I think.

Comment: The `a` element is used to create hyperlinks and should contain only one child element. Usually, this child element is a text node that represents the clickable link text.
For SEO purposes, it is essential to have meaningful and descriptive link text within the anchor element. This helps search engines understand the context and relevance of the link, potentially improving the SEO of your page.

Comment: @sadeqshahmoradi  I’ve never heard of an anchor element having to have only one child. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Why use a link if you don't want it to act like a link?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

> If one of the element's children has pointer-events explicitly set to allow that child to be the target of pointer events, then any events targeting that child will pass through the parent as the event travels along the parent chain, and trigger event listeners on the parent as appropriate.

Therefore if you set any child with pointer events, it will bubble up to the parent.

Answer (score -1):

The following worked almost as intended:

```html
<a href={tab.url ? tab.url : "javascript:void(0)"} >
```

The only problem is it shows `'javascript:void(0)'` as the link, but otherwise works ok and the link is unclickable.

Comment: I don't really think this is the answer based on what you wrote, but glad you solved it anyway!

Comment: Thanks. It's not exactly what I wanted but it is what I needed.